# Necessity of the 'rot' operator

Tags: computation-theory, formal-languages, computation, forth, stack-based

Why does Forth implement the `rot` operator, and why does it operate on exactly the three top-most items of the stack?

Is it just for convenience or would Forth not be Turing-complete without such an instruction? Is the number of three the minimum viable option to be Turing complete?

I can imagine one could implement `rot` with `pick` or `roll`. So if there was none of these three operations, would it still be Turing-complete?

Comment: It is a primitive stack-based language, having to shuffle the top-of-stack values around to get the job done is a very common need.  So lots of vocabulary for it: dup, ?dup, drop, swap, over, nip, tuck, rot, -rot,  Sure, convenience.

Comment: @HansPassant Please see the edit, does still mean it's for convenience?

Comment: Many processors implement it. It makes sense to provide it in the language. I used a language in the 1970s that had an IMP operator.

Answer (score 7):

This topic has nothing to do with Turing-completeness at all.

`rot` operation is for convenience and efficiency only. It can be defined using `swap`:

```
: rot ( a b c -- b c a ) >R SWAP R> SWAP ;
```

`pick` and `roll` can be also implemented using return stack (these `>R` and `R>` operations), or any other stack.

A stack can be implemented using memory access words.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at some minimal FORTH, like [jonesforth](http://git://git.annexia.org/jonesforth.git) or [lbForth](https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/lbForth.git) (both are git repositories). It is rather surprising how little in terms of primitives is required to get off the ground.